# symfony2 form builder load choices from joined table

Tags: php, symfony

I have two tables that are joined together and I want to create a insert form for one table that adds choices from the other table. Example:

**Table Interested**

```
namespace Nbois\CRMBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nbois\CRMBundle\Repository\InterestedRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="crm_interested")
 */
class Interested {

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;



  //.....OTHER FIELDS


  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sex", inversedBy="interested")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sex_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $sex;

  public function getSex(){
    return $this->sex;
  }

  public function setSex(Sex $sex){
    $this->sex = $sex;
    return $this;
  }
  // .... GET AND SET METHODS
  // ....

}
```

**Table Sex**

```
namespace Nbois\CRMBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sex")
 */
class Sex {
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
   * @Assert\NotBlank()
   */
  private $name;

  /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Interested", mappedBy="sex")
  */
  protected $interested;

  public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getName(){
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function setName($name){
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
  }
}
```

I want to add a new **Interested** client, the form builder looks like this:

```
class InterestedType extends AbstractType {
  /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
        ......
        ->add('sex', EntityType::class, array(
              'class' => 'NboisCRMBundle:Sex',
              'choice_label' => 'Sex',
              'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
              'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
              }
          ));
     }

     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
     {
         $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Nbois\CRMBundle\Entity\Interested'
        ));
      }
}
```

And in the controller:

```
public function newAction(Request $request){

    $interested = new Interested();
    $form = $this->createForm(InterestedType::class, $interested);


    return $this->render('NboisCRMBundle:Default:newInterested.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
  }
```

And when I render the form I get this error:

> Neither the property "Sex" nor one of the methods "getSex()", "sex()",
>   "isSex()", "hasSex()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class
>   "Nbois\CRMBundle\Entity\Sex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

choice_label refers to the property 'sex' in sex which does not exist

Something like this should work:

```
          'choice_label' => 'name',
```

[Docs on choice label](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label)

Also maybe you just wanted a regular boring label, in which case you'd use 'label' not 'choice_label'

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. I have all this settings and still get that error. Weird.

Comment: No prob, what does your form rendering look like in your twig template (newInterested.html.twig)?